# CSS not stretching background 100%

Tags: css

for some reason I cannot get my background on my left column to stretch to 100% height.

here are the 2 classes that i have in my css:

```
#page {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 65px;           
}

#leftmain {
    background:url(images/leftmain.gif);
    background-size:15% 100%;
    border:1px solid #c3c2c2;
    width:15%;
    height:100% !important;
    float:left;
}

#leftmain .cssmenu {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

#leftmain .cssmenu ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftmain .cssmenu ul {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}

#leftmain .cssmenu ul li {
    min-height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    line-height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="content>    
        <div id="leftmain>
            <div class="cssmenu">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightmain">    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

if i change the `min-height` on the `.cssmenu` to a fixed `height`, lets say `500px` it shows the background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your HTML code and build a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: So, is this your situation? http://jsfiddle.net/Kbgg5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#leftmain` actually never reaches 100% height. That's why setting a fixed `min-height` works. `#leftmain` in your case can only reach 100% height of its parent if all parents itself have a `height` of `100%`. `min-height` is no enough in this situation.

You need to set `height: 100%` like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbgg5/1/):

```
html,
body,
#page,
#content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This did help thank you. I found that the major cause of this particular issue was that I added a padding of 65px to the rightmain class and it threw it off. Now to fix the footer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#leftmain { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/